# Glassfish web.xml servlet mapping to @WebService gets ClassCastException

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, jax-ws

Am trying to gain control over the URL endpoints of my web services when deployed to Glassfish (and preferably to TomEE too).

I have a class:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(
    targetNamespace = "http://foo.net/doc/2012-08-01",
    name = "FooService",
    portName = "FooPort",
    serviceName = "FooService")
public class FooSoapService extends SoapBase {
...
}
```

And a web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <description>SOAP Endpoint for Foo operations.</description>
    <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.FooSoapService</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FooPack</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/soap/FooPack</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I visit /context-root/soap/FooPack?wsdl when deployed in Glassfish I end up with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foo.FooSoapService cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

There's virtually nothing else in the web.xml excepting some jax-rs stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `FooSoapService` class which you are claiming to be a web service implementation class needs to implement the service interface, probably `FooService` defined in your `@WebService` annotation `serviceName` property.

The reason you are getting this exception is because your `FooSoapService` class is not an instance of `javax.servlet.Servlet` and it is for sure that it does not need to be one. In your web.xml you can't expose your web service endpoint. It needs to be done via `sun-jaxws.xml`. Something like this:

```
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
     <endpoint name="FooPort" implementation="com.foo.FooSoapService" url-pattern="/services/FooService"/>
</endpoints>
```

And your web.xml should look something like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/FooService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you would make those changes then you would be able to get the WSDL from:

```
/context-root/services/FooService?wsdl
```

Comment: This presumably won't work when deployed to TomEE though? I'm really aiming for compatibility, especially important when trying to decide which to use in production (we could even use both)>

Comment: Why you think it won't work in TomEE? It is the general way to create JAX-WS based web services. This is not some king of workaround or something, it is just how it should be and should work on all containers which supports JAX-WS.

Comment: Because TomEE has no com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener (see http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/).

Comment: So whats the problem? Add the `jaxws-rt-x.x.x.jar` in your classpath and thats it. From that link you have given, I assume you are using CXF, so why not just use CXF approach to expose the web service?

Comment: It proves very difficult to make a build that supports both. Quite frankly it's disappointing that a vendor-neutral deployment descriptor holds vendor specific references for it to work. It also ends up looking very complex and, add another application server, you end up potentially needing to configure for it too.

Comment: spec mandates containers to support webservices defined as servlet in web.xml for pojo deployment (opposed to EJB webservices). TomEE+ supports it out of the box and all glassfish should. Having to define WSServletContextListener is not portable at all and is surely wrong if you want any portability.

Comment: I tested this configuration and it is also compatible with Payara 5

Answer (score 0):

glassfish 4.0 has this capability too. The configuration is deployable without errors.