# Change JAX-WS Service URL

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

Is there any Possibility to change the Webservice URL when creating a JAX-WS webservice?

The automatic URL is (on Glassfish 3): `http://<host>/<context>/<Servicename>`, but what i need is: `http://<host>/<context>/axis/services/<Servicename>` (because it is a port from axis to JAX-WS)

**Is there any way to tell JAX-WS where to publish a WS?**

Using sun-jaxws.xml is no option, because it disables @EJB/@Inject DI.

Comment: There is no `@Path` at JAX-WS, `@Path` is an Annotation for Restful services. But I tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the servlet mapping for your JAX-WS implementation class. By default, the servlet mapping is not required and JAX-WS framework generates it for you. As you want to provide a custom URL mapping for your web service service, you can provide a servlet mapping with the custom URL.

Sample:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>CalculatorService</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CalculatorService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.geronimo.samples.jws.CalculatorService
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CalculatorService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/axis/services/calculator</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Refer to https://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC20/simple-web-service-with-jax-ws.html and http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftwbs_customwebxml.html.

Comment: I already tried this. but all I get is an Exception:
org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand execute
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [webservice] : There is no web component by the name of MyWebservice here.
WARNING: Error occurred
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no web component by the name of MyWebservice here.
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.web.WebCommonNode.endElement(WebCommonNode.java:228)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:481)
        at ...

Comment: This may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156171/glassfish-web-xml-servlet-mapping-to-webservice-gets-classcastexception.

Comment: This is completely different to your answer... But as I already wrote in my question: I can't use sun-jaxws.xml because it destroys the EJB/CDI abilities from the web service. FYI: I already asked google...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with the same context. Some axis2 web services to pass in JAX-WS ; so I had to keep the same url mapping (http://[host]:[port]/[context]/services/[serviceName]).

At first, I tried with @WebServlet annotation with an url pattern on the impl class of the WS. It works on JBoss AS 7.1 and Weblogic Server 12 but WebSphere AS 8 didn't like. This is because of the non extending of HttpServlet class but if you done the same by the web.xml, it works.

For one web service to add in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>OMInjector</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fr.fmoisson.kijq.services.OMInjector</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OMInjector</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/OMInjector</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but Glassfish ignores the `@WebServlet` Annotation and when I configure it in web.xml the following exception occures: `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: packagename.IoWebService cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet`