# Publish Jax-WS Webservice under specified Path

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am working on a SOAP Web Service in an Glassfish 4 application server.
The SOAP service itself is working, but I want to publish it under a specified context or path. But I can't find any solution how to do this.

This is my service:

```
@WebService(
    serviceName = "HelloPersonService",
    targetNamespace = "http://example.nl/hellopersonservice/1.0",
    portName = "HelloPersonServicePort",
    wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/my.wsdl",
    endpointInterface="my.HelloPersonServicePortType")
public class HelloPersonServiceImpl
    implements HelloPersonServicePortType {

    @Override
    public HelloPersonServiceResponseType greetPerson(HelloPersonServiceRequestType helloPersonServiceRequest) {
       return null;
    }

}
```

In the moment the service is available under this url:

```
/webservice/HelloPersonService
```

but I want to move it to:

```
/webservice/collection/HelloPersonService
```

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you very much,
arres

Comment: You can change your context-root in web.xml

Comment: @JakubHr it isn't about the context root. See my post, "/%context%/%path%/%service%".

Answer (score 2):

I could finally manage it to configure the path for the webservice. This is possible by adding a jax-ws deploymentdescriptor "sun-jaxws.xml".

There it is possible to add a parameter called "url-pattern" for each service.

@Dubas thank you for your help. your hint pointed into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAX-WS servlet change the servlet path to point the desired path.

If you are using automatic JAX-WS generation (like Websphere 7) you should try changing the serviceName = "HelloPersonService" to  serviceName = "collection/HelloPersonService"

More information about servlet : [Change JAX-WS Service URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680661/change-jax-ws-service-url)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but editing the serviceName doesn't work. The application server throrws exceptions, that this is not a vaild serviceName. The information on the page you posted does work work for glassfish. But I will try to edit the Jax-Ws Servlet configuration. I hope I find something.

Answer (score 0):

In your publisher class,
you can change your published endpoint URL as per your requirement.

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/webservice/HelloPersonService", new HelloPersonServiceImpl());

 Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/webservice/collection/HelloPersonService", new HelloPersonServiceImpl());
```

Comment: I managed to publish the endpoint the way you described in an standalone application but not in a web-context. Can you tell me how I do this inside an application-server?