# How to expose a JaxWS webservice endpoint at a different URL?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a class named AppService, annotated with JaxWS annotations: `@WebService`, `@WebMethod`.

It deploys correctly, and exposes an endpoint at the URL `http://myhost/myapp/AppService`.

I need to respond to a slightly different URL, at http://myhost/myapp/**services**/AppService (notice the 'services' segment).

How should I change the annotations or xml files in the application in order to expose the services under this new URL ?

This application is deployed on `IBM WebSphere`. Usage of standard `JavaEE` API would be preferred, but WebSphere specific instructions are fair game as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a servlet mapping in the web.xml: [Change JAX-WS Service URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680661/change-jax-ws-service-url)